# Como ajustar tamanho do Select em Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-3

Estou aprendendo `Bootstrap` pra fazer uma página simples e quero aumentar o tamanho do meu `Select`. Vejam o código atual:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Selecione o Estabelecimento:</h3>
            <select class="form-control" id="comboEstabelecimento">
                    <option value="2017053290201706130726082"></option>
                    <option value="2605006453163">CAPS CUPIRA </option>
                    <option value="2605002631393">CENTRO DE SAUDE </option>
                    <option value="2605006934323">CEO CUPIRA</option>
                    <option value="2605007720475">DEPARTAMENTO DE VIGILANCIA AMBIENTAL</option>
                    <option value="2605007559267">DEPARTAMENTO DE VIGILANCIA SANITARIA</option>
                    <option value="2605006341845">ESF CAIXA DAGUA </option>
                    <option value="2605002631520">ESF CHA DAS PANELAS </option>
                    <option value="2605006118143">ESF COHAB </option>
                    <option value="2605006341802">ESF DA GLORIA </option>
                    <option value="2605002631482">ESF LAJE DE SAO JOSE</option>
                    <option value="2605002631504">ESF MUTIRAO </option>
                    <option value="2605002631458">ESF NOVO HORIZONTE</option>
                    <option value="2605002631512">ESF PRESIDENTE VARGAS </option>
                    <option value="2605002631490">ESF SAMBAQUIM </option>
                    <option value="2605002354845">HOSPITAL MUNICIPAL JOSE VERISSIMO DE SOUZA</option>
                    <option value="2605007735367">LABORATORIO DE PROTESE SPDENTE</option>
                    <option value="2605006359558">NASF</option>
                    <option value="2605007528183">POLO ACADEMIA DAS CIDADES DE CUPIRA </option>
                    <option value="2605006134149">SAMU</option>
                    <option value="2605006470033">SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE SAUDE DE CUPIRA </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Vejam como fica na tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O componente fica menor que o texto que está dentro. Como corrigir?

Obs.: Estou preenchendo esses dados dinamicamente usando `C#`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o width do CSS para corrigir isso.

```css
#comboEstabelecimento{
 width:auto;   
}
```

```html
<h3>Selecione o Estabelecimento:</h3>
<select class="form-control" id="comboEstabelecimento">
    <option value="2017053290201706130726082"></option>
    <option value="2605006453163">CAPS CUPIRA </option>
    <option value="2605002631393">CENTRO DE SAUDE </option>
    <option value="2605006934323">CEO CUPIRA</option>
    <option value="2605007720475">DEPARTAMENTO DE VIGILANCIA AMBIENTAL</option>
    <option value="2605007559267">DEPARTAMENTO DE VIGILANCIA SANITARIA</option>
    <option value="2605006341845">ESF CAIXA DAGUA </option>
    <option value="2605002631520">ESF CHA DAS PANELAS </option>
    <option value="2605006118143">ESF COHAB </option>
    <option value="2605006341802">ESF DA GLORIA </option>
    <option value="2605002631482">ESF LAJE DE SAO JOSE</option>
    <option value="2605002631504">ESF MUTIRAO </option>
    <option value="2605002631458">ESF NOVO HORIZONTE</option>
    <option value="2605002631512">ESF PRESIDENTE VARGAS </option>
    <option value="2605002631490">ESF SAMBAQUIM </option>
    <option value="2605002354845">HOSPITAL MUNICIPAL JOSE VERISSIMO DE SOUZA</option>
    <option value="2605007735367">LABORATORIO DE PROTESE SPDENTE</option>
    <option value="2605006359558">NASF</option>
    <option value="2605007528183">POLO ACADEMIA DAS CIDADES DE CUPIRA </option>
    <option value="2605006134149">SAMU</option>
    <option value="2605006470033">SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE SAUDE DE CUPIRA</option>
</select>
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9w054en/).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas colocar um valor fixo (350px) não irá resolver caso eu precise inserir mais itens de tamanho maiores. Preciso de uma forma que o `Select` se ajuste dinamicamente.

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta(css), veja se funciona como você queria agora.

Comment: Também não. Vi que no exemplo que você postou funciona com `width:100%;` a questão deve ser com o Bootstrap mesmo.

Comment: Pode ser porque eu preencho os itens dinamicamente. Deixa quieto então. Obrigado.